# Difference between definition of a limit if a function and definition of continuity.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, definition

I am having trouble understanding why this particular difference exists between the definition of a limit of a function and definition of continuity.

Heres the definition of a limit of a sequence.

> Let f : A → R, where A ⊂ R, and suppose that c ∈ R is an
>   accumulation point of A. Then
>   lim f(x) = L x→c
>   if for every ε > 0 there exists a δ > 0 such that
>   0 < |x − c| < δ and x ∈ A implies that |f(x) − L| < ε.

I noticed that this definition requires $0 < |x - c| < \delta$

> Let f : A → R, where A ⊂ R, and suppose that c ∈ A. Then f is continuous at c if for every ε > 0 there exists a δ > 0 such that
>   |x−c| < δ and x ∈ A implies that |f(x)−f(c)| < ε.

whereas the definition of continuity above requires only $|x -  c| < \delta$, so $|x - c$| can be 0.

Why is this the case?

Comment: Limits don't care about what's happening at the point you're approaching, only what's happening near that point. Continuity depends on how the behavior near the point relates to the behavior at the point itself.

Answer (score 5):

Here are the differences:

$0 < |x - c| < \delta$ means that we are not imposing any conditions on the function for $x = c$, while in the definition of continuity, we have $|x -c | < \delta$. The difference is that in the definition of continuity at $c$, we insist that the function also be defined at $x = c$, but we don't in the definition of limit.

The conclusion $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$ in the definition of limit is different from $|f(x) - f(c)| < \varepsilon$ in the definition of continuity at $c$. The conclusion $|f(x) - f(c) | < \varepsilon$ actually is saying two things: that the limit exists, and further that the limit is $f(c)$.

To sum up, continuity at $c$ means essentially means the following three things:

1) The limit exists at $x = c$.

2) The function $f$ is defined when $x = c$.

3) The limit $f(x)$ as $x\to c$ is exactly $f(c)$.

A function having a limit need only satisfy the first of these three things.