# What functions are continuous under the two prevailing definitions of continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

This [very interesting question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1979605/whats-the-purpose-of-the-two-different-definitions-used-for-limit?) asks about 2 definitions of **continuity**

**Definition**.
Let $\Bbb{R}$ be the real numbers.
Let $\Bbb{R}^+$ be the positive real numbers.
Let $f: [a , b] \to \Bbb{R}$ be an $\Bbb{R}$-valued function on the closed-closed interval $[a,b] \subseteq \Bbb{R}$.
Let $\text{Dom}(f)$ be the domain of $f: [a , b] \to \Bbb{R}$.

Now the function $f: [a , b] \to \Bbb{R}$ is continuous at $a \in \operatorname{Dom}(f)$ **iff**

0. $\forall \epsilon \in \Bbb{R}^+\ \exists \delta \in \Bbb{R}^+ \ \forall x\in \text{Dom}(f) \left< 0<|x-a|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon \right>\ $ or
1. $\forall \epsilon \in \Bbb{R}^+\ \exists \delta \in \Bbb{R}^+ \ \forall x\in \text{Dom}(f) \left< |x-a|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon \right>\ $

(I think definition 0 is using **punctured neighborhoods**, meaning neighborhoods of $a$ that exclude $a$, and I'm curious as to what the consequences of this are.)

**Questions.**

- What are some examples of functions in the "symmetric difference" of the 2 definitions? (The functions that are continuous under definition 0 and *not* continuous under definition 1, and the functions that are *not* continuous under definition 0 and continuous under definition 1.)
- Is there a "characterization" of the functions in the "symmetric difference"?
- What are some theorems/results in the "symmetric difference" of the 2 definitions? (Theorems/results that are true for continuous functions when using definition 0 and false when using definition 1, and theorems/results that are false for continuous functions when using definition 0 and true when using definition 1.)
- In what ways does the development of calculus/analysis on $\Bbb{R}$ differ when using each definition?

Comment: If $|x-a|=0$, then $x=a$ and therefore also $|f(x)-f(a)|= 0$. Am I missing something?

Comment: We would find the differences if there were a $ y \neq x $ such that $ d (x, y) = 0 $. That is, in $\mathbb{R}$ there is no difference if we equip it with a norm. More generally, there is no difference in any normed space. In non-normed spaces it can be interesting.

Comment: What exactly is $| \cdot |$ supposed to mean if not a norm? In metric spaces, we have $d(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y$.

Comment: The question you link to asks about two definitions of **limit**, not of continuity. While the two definitions would amount to different things for *limits* (which do not require the function to be defined at the point), they are equivalent for *continuity*, which does require the function to be defined at the point. Limits as $x\to a$ do not actually care what the value of $f$ is at $a$ (if any), while continuity at $a$ does.

Comment: @NiklasvMoers the semi-norms are precisely those that allow there to be non-zero elements with semi-norm zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These definitions are equivalent, unlike the case for limits, as in the question you link. Limits do not inherently refer to $f(a)$, so allowing $|x-a|$ to vanish adds something in that case but not in this one.

Answer (score 0):

Definition $0$ describes $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=f(a)$ if $a$ is a limit point. Even if $a$ is not a limit point, this definition still works because we can choose $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x-a|<\delta$ never occurs for any $x\in Dom(f)$. Hence, the conclusion $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$ is vacuously true for "any such $x$."

Definition $1$ is equivalent because if $f(a)$ exists, it has to be true that $0=|a-a|<\delta \implies 0=|f(a)-f(a)|<\epsilon$.